# How to preserve quotes in BibTeX

Tags: latex, bibtex

I'm new to LaTeX and BibTeX, so excuse my ignorance. I have the following entry:

```
@Article{Hart,
author = {P.E. Hart, N.J. Nilsson, B. Raphael},
title = {Correction to \"A Formal Basis for the Heuristic Determination of Minimum Cost Paths\" },
journal = {SIGART Newsletter 37},
year = {1972},
pages = {28-29}
}
```

But this comes out as a capital letter A with diaeresis (Ä) and a ':', respectively. How do you get BibTeX to display quotes in a title?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, quotes should be done like ``` ``this'' ``` (with back-ticks and apostrophes). Second, wrapping this in braces `{like this}` protects it from being messed with by bibtex. (You need to do this to get capital letters in article titles, for instance.

Comment: And this site: http://tex.stackexchange.com/ is probably a better place to ask your TeX questions in future.

Comment: Thanks - I'll do that next time. Your advice helped, but now, instead of quotes I'm getting ¨ (two small dots). This is the code, did I understand correctly? title = {Correction to {``}A Formal Basis for the Heuristic Determination of Minimum Cost Paths{''}

Comment: First try just `title={Correction to ``A formal basis... paths''}`

Comment: Ah.. I had to recompile twice to see the effects, I think that's what I didn't do last time. Thanks.